# extract integer value from webelement and compare again using cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7y32.png)

How to extract 3 from this and compare it with same if this integer value changes
3

Comment: Can you provide any examples of things you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Easy ways to extract element text and compare it with expected value are:

```js
cy.get(locatorOfElement).invoke("text").then((value) => {
    expect(value).to.equal("3");
});
```

```js
cy.get(locatorOfElement).invoke("text").should("be.eq", "3");
```

and if you want to compare it with integer value then you have to convert the extracted value to an integer and then compare it to an expected integer value.

```js
cy.get(locatorOfElement).invoke("text").then((value) => {
    expect(parseInt(value)).to.equal(3);
});
```

```js
cy.get(locatorOfElement).invoke("text").then(parseInt).should('eq', 3)
```